# Display openweathermap (API) data on website using AJAX

Tags: ajax, openweathermap

I am struggling to display the data from the weather API in my webpage. I am working on a localhost, and I am able to do various console logs successfully.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Weather App</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>Weather App</h1>
    <h2>Choose Location</h2>
    <span id="error"></span>
    <input type="text" name="city" id="city" placeholder="City Name">
    <button id="submitLocation">Find</button>
    <div id="show"></div>


    <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/weather.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

weather.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#submitLocation').click(function(){

        //get value from input field
        var city = $("#city").val();

        //check not empty
        if (city != ''){

            $.ajax({

                url: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + city + "&units=metric" + "&APPID=MYID",
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                    console.log(data.weather[0].main);
                    console.log(data.main);
                    console.log(data.main.temp);

                    var information = show(data);
                    $("#show").html(information);
                }
            });

        }else{
            $('#error').html('Field cannot be empty');
        }

    });
})

function show(data){
    return  
    "<h3>Current Weather: "+ data.main.temp +"</h3>" +
    "<h3>Current Weather: "+ data.main.description +"</h3>";
    // "<h3>Current Weather: "+ data.weather[0].main +"</h3>" 
}
```

console logs return the following:

console.log(data);

```
{coord: {…}, weather: Array(1), base: "stations", main: {…}, visibility: 10000, …}
base
:
"stations"
clouds
:
{all: 90}
cod
:
200
coord
:
{lon: -0.13, lat: 51.51}
dt
:
1522885800
id
:
2643743
main
:
{temp: 6.78, pressure: 1001, humidity: 70, temp_min: 5, temp_max: 8}
name
:
"London"
sys
:
{type: 1, id: 5091, message: 0.0044, country: "GB", sunrise: 1522906029, …}
visibility
:
10000
weather
:
[{…}]
wind
:
{speed: 8.2, deg: 270}
__proto__
:
Object
```

console.log(data.weather[0].main);

```
Clouds
```

console.log(data.main);

```
{temp: 6.78, pressure: 1001, humidity: 70, temp_min: 5, temp_max: 8}
humidity
:
70
pressure
:
1001
temp
:
6.78
temp_max
:
8
temp_min
:
5
__proto__
:
Object
```

console.log(data.main.temp);

```
6.78
```

I am getting no errors, and with the console logs working I am assuming the problem is how I am attempting to display the data or maybe a syntax error I am overlooking?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed this:

```
function show(data){
    return  
    "<h3>Current Weather: "+ data.main.temp +"</h3>" +
    "<h3>Current Weather: "+ data.main.description +"</h3>";
    // "<h3>Current Weather: "+ data.weather[0].main +"</h3>" 
}
```

To this:

```
function show(data){
    return "<h3>Current Weather: "+ data.main.temp +"</h3>" + "<h3>Current Weather: "+ data.weather[0].main +"</h3>";
```

I am not sure if it is because I added a return, extra spaces or tabs, but when I moved the code onto one line it started to work.